# MS Word VBA how to make my macro faster, to insert a space before and after a character withe condition's to when to insert the space's?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a Macro for MS Word that will check the document and apply rules to a"/" ":" and a "." it  must add a "Space" before and after a "/" It must add s "Space""Space" after a ":" and a"." only if there is not "space's" as described.

I have used the (Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdMove)  to move the cursor to the place where checks and changes must take place. It work but is unbelievable slow

Hear is my code:

Sub FIX_Space1()

```
Dim Title As String
Dim CharCount As Integer
Dim Message As String
Dim Char1 As String
Dim NextChar As String
Dim NextChar1 As String
Dim x As Long

ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
Selection.WholeStory

Title = "CharCount"
CharCount = Len(Selection)


For x = 0 To CharCount
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=x, Extend:=wdMove
    NextChar = Selection
    '## check for "/"
    If NextChar = "/" Then
       'Check for space one back
       Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdMove
       NextChar1 = Selection
       If NextChar1 = " " Then
       Else
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
        Selection.Text = " "
       End If
       'Check for space one forward
       Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdMove
       NextChar1 = Selection
       If NextChar1 = " " Then
       Else
        Selection.Text = " "
       End If
    End If

    '## check for ":"
    If NextChar = ":" Then
       'Check for : one forward
       Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
       NextChar1 = Selection
       If NextChar1 = " " Then
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
            NextChar1 = Selection
            If NextChar1 = " " Then
            Else
                Selection.Text = " "
            End If
       Else
        Selection.Text = "  "
       End If
    End If

    '## check for "."
    If NextChar = "." Then
       'Check for : one forward
       Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
       NextChar1 = Selection
       If NextChar1 = " " Then
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
            NextChar1 = Selection
            If NextChar1 = " " Then
            Else
                Selection.Text = " "
            End If
       Else
        Selection.Text = "  "
       End If
    End If

Next x
```

End Sub

Comment: Okay, you can use the [AutoCorrect](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/07/add-words-to-autocorrect-entries.html) feature to replace text with other text which, while it may not cover all of the cases you listed, should cover some of them (ex replace: `"/"` with: `" / "`)

Comment: Otherwise it might make more sense to use replace or find and then navigate a handful of characters left and right of the found range instead of having it loop through every single character in the document

Comment: @Willie-Taljaard You might want to rethink what you're doing. Applying double spaces after every . could make a real mess of abbreviations such as e.g., i.e., etc. Applying double spaces after every : can make a mess of times, ratios, biblical chapter:verse references and so on. Applying spaces before & after every / could make a mess of dates & fractions, as well as to common expressions like and/or.